# Firebase and Swift 3 code not executing anymore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, tableview, firebase-realtime-database

I tried to convert my code `func` by `func` to Swift 3. I have to say that I had fully working project before. Now I have problem where I have no errors and just some warnings but some of the functions are not being executed. What should cause this?

I only assume that those given functions are faulty because these are the parts where I am not getting anything even `print`.

These are some of my functions that worked before but not with Swift 3:

```
//With this I get selected brand products values like product name, nicotine, flavor etc..
 let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Snuses").queryOrdered(byChild: "Brand").queryEqual(toValue: brandName)
      ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
           if snapshot.exists(){
                if let products = (snapshot.value as AnyObject).allValues as? [[String:AnyObject]]{
                    self.productsValue = products
                    self.productsTable.reloadData()
                }
           }
  })

//With this fucntion I get the products count.
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Snuses").queryOrdered(byChild: "Brand").queryEqual(toValue: filteredBrands[indexPath.row])
                ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                    if snapshot.exists(){
                        if let products = (snapshot.value as AnyObject).allValues as? [[String:AnyObject]]{

                                var count = (snapshot.childrenCount)
                                snusProductCountLabel.text = "\(count) products"

                        }
                    }
                })

//Parse snus brands
    func parseSnuses(){
        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Brands").queryOrderedByKey()

        ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            self.brands.append(snapshot.key)
            print(snapshot.key)
            self.snusBrandsTableView.reloadData()
        }){ (error) in

        }
```

Anything I can do different please tell me! Those functions are in different `ViewControllers`.

Edit: this is my JSON tree

```
{
  "Snuses" : {
    "Catch Eucalyptus White Large" : {
          "Brand" : "Catch",
          "Products" : "Catch Eucalyptus White Large",
          "PorionWeight" : 21.6,
          "flavor" : "Tobacco, Eucalyptus",
          "nicotine" : 8.0,
          "PortionsCan" : 24,
          "shipping weight" : 39
        },
```

And these are security rules:

```
{ 
  "rules": { 
     ".read": "true", 
     ".write": "true", 
     "Snuses": { 
        ".indexOn": "Brand"
     } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: what exactly are you seeing, in terms of errors? Not clear what the issue is...

Comment: No errors just the code not giving anything.

Comment: what does "code not giving anything" mean, then? What should the code "give you"?

Comment: Update your question with your JSON tree, and your security rules also state wether or not your user is authenticated before using any of the function's. Secondly its too broad...

Comment: I updated my question. In code comments you see wha tit should give. For example in the last one it should give all "Brands" e.g "Catch".

Comment: Please don't use images in your questions! It's not searchable and if we need to change it, we have to re-type it. Export your structure from the Firebase console and copy/paste.

Comment: Your code works for me. I duplicated your structure in a project and ran the first query. Other than some unwrapping optional issues, it executed correctly. Although if let products = line is a little suspect in what it's returning - what are you expecting there as it's nil with .allValues

Comment: Sorry, I added the tree as code but I don't understand why then it is not working for me.. What output you get?

Comment: I should get the first func output after selecting row in tableview.

Comment: If the let products = line is commented out and we a print(snapshot) is added, the structure is printed. Let me throw an answer in and see if changing the code helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the

```
if let products = (snapshot.value as AnyObject)
                   .allValues as? [[String:AnyObject]]{
```

is the issue.

Try this as a test to see if it prints the data from the snapshot:

```
 let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Snuses")
               .queryOrdered(byChild: "Brand").queryEqual(toValue: brandName)
      ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
           if snapshot.exists() {

                let dict = snapshot?.value as! [String: [String:String]]
                let productsArray = Array(dict)

                for row in productsArray {
                     print(row)
                }
           }
 })
```

for a non-swifty test, you can also try this inside the closure instead of the above

```
let d2 = snapshot?.value as! NSDictionary
let a2 = d2.allValues

for r2 in a2 {
     print(r2)
}
```

one more option:

```
let q = snapshot?.value as! [String: AnyObject]
let a3 = Array(q)

for r3 in a3 {
     print(r3)
}
```

I don't know what your tableView is expecting in the array but one of those should cover it.

Comment: This makes new issues like: 'InvalidQueryParameter', reason: 'You can only pass nil, NSString or NSNumber to queryEqualToValue:' if you want I can share my repo at Github and have some time.

Comment: You would need to define brandName = to something before executing that code. The code is working for me.

Comment: Absolutely :D I did it. My "brandName" is indexPath.row. And I did it.

Comment: That may be where the issue is then. Take out the indexPath.row and substitute the actual string   *.queryEqual(toValue: "Catch")* as that's working for all of my above examples and returning the snapshot.

Comment: Still nothing.. Ahh.. what ever. I do not understand why it worked in Swift 2? Nothing has changed since then, logic is the same and functionality.

Comment: Only function that is working is parseSnuses() Others just not showing nothing even if I specify to query like "Catch" etc..

Comment: I duplicated your structure in Firebase and also used the above code in my answer (with let brand = "Catch") and it works and prints the data from the Snapshot in each case. If your code isn't working then it's either something outside the Firebase functions or perhaps a security rule setting. I would copy/paste my code in place of yours to see what happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124742/discussion-between-tarvo-maesepp-and-jay).

Comment: You are right. This line caused the isse. I removed it and it works.